# Claims/Forms Auth and Secure Store - good use?

Tags: forms-authentication, claims-based-auth, single-sign-on, secure-store

I have a need to provide single sign on capabilities within the same enterprise - meaning sometimes I'll need access to the user's name and password.  A few examples:

1. SSO to OWA (forms based)
2. SSO to "legacy" portal - custom form / cookie
3. SSO to other BASIC authentication applications

Right now there is custom code / ISAPIs that will translate a cookie into a BASIC authentication header.  I am looking at alternatives to that process - potentially more secure / claims based approaches.

One option I can think of would be the following:

1. Enable Forms authentication + AD/LDAP membership provider
2. Once authenticated programmatically store/update the user's credentials in the secure  store
3. Leverage the secure store to get current user's
   credentials needed to sign on to the other systems

Is this a good use of the secure store?  Would it be better to add the user name/password to the forms auth cookie/ticket (encrypted)?

Is there anyway to translate a Forms ticket to a Basic Authentication Header?

What are some of the things others have done to accomplish SSO between enterprise applications?